# Modify each version of the polyhedron with an image

Tags: image3d, polyhedra

I'm new here and want to represent a Polyhedron with every face filled with my own `Image` of choice.

The Polyhedron is the DuerersSolid: `PolyhedronData["DuerersSolid", "Image"]`

Answer (score 2):

Slightly modified version of the example from the docs: [Texture >> Neat Examples >> Textures on Polyhedra](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Texture.html)

```
Manipulate[Graphics3D[{Specularity[White, 20], 
   Texture[ImageCrop[ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "WhiteMarble"}], {128, 128}]], 
   EdgeForm[Opacity[1/10]], (Append[#1, {VertexTextureCoordinates -> 
     (CirclePoints[{1, 0}, Length[First @ #]] + 1)/2}]&) /@
       Flatten[Normal[PolyhedronData[p, "Faces"]]]}, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral"], {{p, "RhombicHexecontahedron", "polyhedron"}, PolyhedronData[]}]
```

[image]

```
texture = Texture[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]];
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Thick, White}], texture, 
 (Append[#1, {VertexTextureCoordinates -> 
     (CirclePoints[{1, 0}, Length[First @ #]] + 1)/2}]&) /@ 
       Flatten[Normal[PolyhedronData["DuerersSolid", "Faces"]]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!! That was really useful!!

Comment: @MattiaRugna, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.