# Changing the length of the edge of the Polyhedron

Tags: image3d, polyhedra

Hope you're having a great day!

I made [another post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198780/modify-each-version-of-the-polyhedron-with-an-image) in regard of how to insert an image onto a face of a Polyhedron. 
I hope you could help me on this one too!

I want to change the length of the edges of my netimage polyhedron without changing his 3D model. Is it possible?

My polyhedron is:

```
PolyhedronData["DuerersSolid", "NetImage"]
```

I want to change its edges. Is it possible?

Comment: To clarify, for my own interest: you want to have essentially the base 3D model be modified? But still remain the same? This is pedagogically opposed in my brain, can you explain what you are looking for slightly more? You can most definitely change the length of sides as you wish (I do not know how off-hand) but you would then change the model into a new one? (To my understanding then, the 3D model would be different.)

Comment: yeah! The first thing you said! I want to modify the lenght of the edges without changing the actual Polyhedron

Comment: so, do you mean to enlarge it?

Comment: Yeah, I actually want to change its size and lenght :)

Answer (score 2):

Since the `"NetImage"` property of `PolyhedronData` is just an `Image`, you can only `ImageResize` it:

```
ImageResize[PolyhedronData["DuerersSolid", "NetImage"], Scaled@2]
```

This can cause rasterization artefacts and defects, which is probably not what you want.

You may want `"Net"` instead:

```
PolyhedronData["DuerersSolid", "Net"]
```

This outputs a scaleable `Graphics` object. You can see in the `InputForm` of this object (`InputForm@PolyhedronData["DuerersSolid", "Net"]`) that it does not have specific units in mind, and is scaleable. To scale it from the notebook interface, simply click on it and drag the handles. To scale it from code, you can use `Show` and `ImageSize` like the following:

```
Show[PolyhedronData["DuerersSolid", "Net"], ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image]

You can also get other types of output from `"Net"`, including `"Graph"` and a list of coordinates.

You can also do things such as create a `MeshRegion` from the `Graphics` object using `DiscretizeGraphics`:

[image]

It's important to note that these properties (`"Net"` and `"NetImage"`) are not computed directly from a 3D object - they are pre-computed.

Comment: Thanks! I want to change the image directly (Moving one edge and twist a triangle, for example), is it possible?

Comment: Perhaps, but you may not be able to easily "reassemble" the polyhedron - is this your ultimate goal?

Comment: Yes, it is! Could you please show me how to do it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how you might best do that. Perhaps if you spend some time searching on this site, you might have some luck!

Comment: Thank you anyway! If i found something interesting I'll let you know then!! :)

Comment: [This might be useful to you.](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FoldingNetsIntoPolyhedra/)